# Simple equation - prove division

Tags: divisibility

this should be simple. I am helping my son with one assignment but I simply cannot solve it. I really exhausted ideas. The problem is:
prove that $\displaystyle {(m^2 + 5m)(m^2 + 5m + 10) + 24}$ can be divided by 24. 
Any hint?

Comment: Well for zero it is one. The expression is equal to 1.

Comment: I assume the question means "if $m$ is an integer, show that $(m^2+5m)(m^2+5m+10)$ is always divisible by $24$", no?

Comment: ror $m=0$ it is ok the statement

Comment: Yes for m is integer.

Comment: Hint:  to check this, you just need to check that it is divisible by $3$ and $8$.  Both of those are very quick checks.

Comment: Exactly, multiple of 24.

Comment: OP: Kf-Sansoo gave an excellent answer. The idea is to factor your expression into something until it becomes clear that your expression is divisible by 24 regardless of the values you use for $m$. Thus, Kf-Sansoo rewrote your original expression as a difference of squares, $A^2-B^2$, and noted that $A^2-B^2=(A-B)(A+B)$. Also, both of these expressions then factored into the final expression he gave. Note that the final expression will always be divisible by 24 whenever you have an integer input $m$. If $m=-1,-2,-3,-4$, then the expression evaluates to $0$ which is, of course, divisible by 24.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A = (m^2+5m + 5)^2 - 1 = (m^2 + 5m + 6)(m^2 + 5m + 4) = (m+1)(m+2)(m+3)(m+4)$ divisible by $4! = 24$.

Comment: Nice insight with the difference of squares equality. How did you see it that quickly? (+1)

Comment: If i see $x^2 + 2nx$ then I think about complete square.

Comment: Thank you, very elegant. But how did you find first brackets that easily?

Comment: @user120250 See my [comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1617129/simple-equation-prove-division#comment3296465_1617129) on your question; I think this will answer your question.

Comment: I found that bracket by completing square - a simple yet powerful litle trick .